# Blazor : How to get HTML of SSRS from controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, reporting-services, blazor

I'm trying to get a report from SSRS Rest API. I can see it when I navigate to the URL
https://myPC:443/ReportService?%2fSSRS%2fPatientèle&rs:Command=Embed&rc:LinkTarget=main&Hospital=CHRU%20Strasbourg
in chrome

When I navigate there in the browser I can see my report.

So I've tried to get the HTML from a controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> GetReportAsHTML()
    {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var result = await client.GetAsync("http://myPC:80/ReportService?%2fSSRS%2fPatientèle&rs:Command=Embed&rc:LinkTarget=main&Hospital=CHRU%20Strasbourg"))
                {
                    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
```

It's returning 401 unauthorized, and the statement in the if is never reached.

Can someone please explain how I can resolve this problem so I get the correct response?

### EDIT

I tried both, I mean in http & https, and both return the report without authentification. Http access (http://localhost:80/...) was even better because charts aren't displayed, only tables. With https access, I get the following picture instead of the charts:

[image: no chart picture]

Comment: Open and see if this url - "http://myPC:80/ReportService?%2fSSRS%2fPatientèle&rs:Command=Embed&rc:LinkTarget=main&Hospital=CHRU%20Strasbourg" opens in the browser. Because this is the nature of HTTP GET. If not then your api is wanting some autorization in the form of keys, JWT token etc. You have to see the api code and find out this thing. Also check the networks tab if there is some or some error which you can paste in your question.

Comment: If your pointing to the report server, it's usually *ReportServer* not *ReportService*.

Comment: @lolveley, Whether you configured the application to use Authentication or not? From your Edit, do you mean the 401 unauthorized disappear? For the charts not displayed issue, you could set a bread point in the action method and check the return data and use F12 developer tools to check the response body whether it contains the correct data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to embed reports, you can also consider doing so in an `<iframe>` - just point its `src` to the report URL.

```
<iframe src="https://myPC:443/ReportService?%2fSSRS%2fPatientèle&rs:Command=Embed&rc:LinkTarget=main&Hospital=CHRU%20Strasbourg "></iframe>
```

The added benefits are:

- iframes usually share cookies with their parent, so if the report server needs such authentication it may work immediately
- if the report is somehow interactive (say, it actually returns an html page with filters, dropodwns and the like) - your end user would get that too instead of static HTML that might even break when taken out of its context

You may also want to look into ready-made Blazor report viewer components - perhaps your reporting solution vendor already has one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like url in your code do not match the one you use through Chrome? Could this be the issue?

Comment: Sadly, no, this is not the reason. plz see my edit.